# Is there a way to efficiently compute the product of two (or more) iterators?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to compute "efficiently" the product of two iterators. Each of them takes a little to yield each result, and there are a lot of yielded results. Since it seems that `itertools.product` first computes all items, it takes quite a lot to get the first pair.

A MCVE is:

```py
import time
from itertools import product

def costlygen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(1)
        yield i

g1 = costlygen(5)
g2 = costlygen(5)

now = time.time()
g = product(g1,g2)

for x in g:
    print(x)
    print(time.time()-now)
```

The output is:

```
(0, 0)
10.027392148971558
(0, 1)
10.027477979660034
(0, 2)
10.027528285980225
...
(4, 3)
10.028220176696777
(4, 4)
10.028250217437744
```

From the results it is clear that `product` computes all the items generated by each of the generators, and hence the first result is only yielded after 10 seconds, when it could have been yielded after only 2 seconds.

Is there any way to get the results as soon as they are produced?

Comment: Based on my testing, the value of the generator isn't computed until it is accessed. When it is accessed, it waits for the termination of the function to continue. So, either when you do `g = product(g1,g2)` or `for x in g`, you need to wait 5 seconds to calculated the value of g1, then g2 (no multithreading by default in python.)

Comment: I read this and what you want is a fair enumerating product that doesn't favor either of the generators. This allows it to take the product of itertools.count(0) and itertools.count(0) and yield values without needing to exhaust the first generator before advancing the second. I remember this from a paper where they were taking the products of infinite generators. I don't have an implementation but if this is what you want it can be got.

Comment: @DanD. yes... this is more or less what I need

Comment: @BielCardona: It seems like you’d be happy with a simpler implementation that didn’t support infinite generators and merely collected values into a list but only after using them to emit all possible tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one possible solution which uses caching via `gone` list:

```
import time
from itertools import product

def costlygen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(1)
        yield i

def simple_product(it1, it2):
    gone = []
    x = next(it1)
    for y in it2:
        gone.append(y)
        yield x, y
    for x in it1:
        for y in gone:
            yield x, y

def complex_product(*iterables):
    if len(iterables) == 2:
        yield from simple_product(*iterables)
        return
    it1, *rest = iterables
    gone = []
    x = next(it1)
    for t in complex_product(*rest):
        gone.append(t)
        yield (x,) + t
    for x in it1:
        for t in gone:
            yield (x,) + t

g1 = costlygen(5)
g2 = costlygen(5)
g3 = costlygen(5)

now = time.time()
g = complex_product(g1,g2,g3)

for x in g:
    print(x)
    print(time.time()-now)
```

Timings:

```
(0, 0, 0)
3.002698898315429  # as soon as possible
(0, 0, 1)
4.003920316696167  # after one second
(0, 0, 2)
5.005135536193848
(0, 0, 3)
6.006361484527588
(0, 0, 4)
7.006711721420288
(0, 1, 0)
8.007975101470947
(0, 1, 1)
8.008066892623901  # third gen was already gone, so (*, *, 1) will be produced instantly after (*, *, 0)
(0, 1, 2)
8.008140802383423
(0, 1, 3)
8.00821304321289
(0, 1, 4)
8.008255004882812
(0, 2, 0)
9.009203910827637
```

Comment: Great! Just a minor correction: I think that in `complex_product`, just after the "`yield from`" line, there must be a `return`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Accidentaly, this code works without `return` because the line `x = next(it1)` raises `StopIteration` that works similar as `return` for a generator function.